# Mac osx -- How to show same app content to all connected displays

Tags: objective-c, macos, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

Working on full screen mac app. I am using webView to show some weather related information. Not able to show the same webView content to all connected monitor screens like it appears on the main screen.(not by using `Airplay-mirroring`).
Currently i am able to set the wallpaper of other displays only. by using ([NSScreen screens])
Could someone please advise me something? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't actually be doing this, because it would interfere with my usage of the other monitor. I have two monitors because I want to be able to run two different apps in fullscreen mode, one on each monitor. Apart from that, create two windows. But don't be surprised if people don't like it.

Comment: After searching abt it i found that we can connect multiple monitors using "Mini displayPort to VGA Adapter". After having more then one screens we can place any window opened in main screen to other monitor. But don't know how to play with secondary monitors programmatically. Can we open any window on secondary monitor through code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so simple. I searched about many related things like "CGDisplayCapture" and "CGShieldingWindowLevel()" but there was no need of that in my case.

1.. Below line will give you all connected screens

```
for (NSScreen *screen in [NSScreen screens]) {  }
```

2.. Now find screen size, because connected displays may have different screen size then the current screen. And alloc a new window with current screen and current screen size as parameter--

```
    // Draw a new window to fill the screen
    NSRect screenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.frame.size.width , screen.frame.size.height);

    secondaryMonitorWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask  backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered  defer:NO  screen:screen];
```

3.. In my case desktop icons should be visible over the window so i set the window level as kCGDesktopWindowLevel. And made this window "makeKeyAndOrderFront".

4.. We can not add any view as subview to multiple windows. And new window needs same view as my mainscreen window has. So i created copy of the same view with this --

```
    id copyOfView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.webView]];
```

5.. Assign same screensize frame to this view and added this to the new window.

```
    [copyOfView setFrame:screenRect];
    [secondaryMonitorWindow.contentView addSubview:(WebView*)copyOfView];
```

And its done. Now to same change to both displays, one has to make change for both window objects.